# How to make a parallel build in Jenkins correctly?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to organize a parallel build in Jenkins. But as a result, for all iterations, I get only the last value ('my').

This is a very simple build. I 'm just copying a file from the folder .env to the root of the site.

```
sh "cp .tasks/env/${job}-PROD .env"
```

But as a result , the file .env is the same as the value from the last iteration ('my').

What am I doing wrong?

This is my Jenkins job:

```
def entitys = ['mt', 'mu', 'bm', 'my' ]
def parallelStagesMap = entitys.collectEntries {
  ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(job) {
  return {
    stage("stage: ${job}") {
        
        sh "cat .tasks/env/${job}-PROD"

        sh "cp .tasks/env/${job}-PROD .env"

        sh "cat .env"

        sh "npm run generate"
    }
  }
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'DATOCMS_ENV', defaultValue: 'dev', description: 'DatoCms environment, optional, if omitted,then it will get Primary environment',trim: true)
    }
    environment {
        BUILD_VERSION = "cms ${DATOCMS_ENV}"
    }
    stages {
        stage("Preparing environment"){
           steps{
               script {
                    currentBuild.displayName = "Build: ${BUILD_VERSION}"
               }
               sh "npm -v"
               sh "node -v"
               sh "rm -rf node_modules"
               sh "npm i"
           }
        }
        stage("Parralel Work Stage") {
          steps {
            script {
              parallel parallelStagesMap
            }
          }
        }
    } 
}
```